# C# Branch code based on client OS

Tags: c#, oop

I'm coming from a scripting background, trying to hack some C# together. So I wasn't sure how to phrase this question, but I'm sure I'm asking it because I don't have the understanding of OOP that I no doubt need!

Basically I have three classes:

```
class OSThingy
class XP : OSThingy
class Win7 : OSThingy
```

The 'OSThingy' class contains common properties and a few methods which both of the derivative classes require. Each of the derivative classes implement an interface that gives them some common methods which differ in implementation. The implementation differs extremely between XP and Windows 7, so I want to keep them in separate classes. I'm also hoping that this design will make it easy to remove the XP related stuff when it is no longer required.

In my program's entry point, I want to create an instance of the correct class depending on if it's running on Windows XP or Windows 7. Here's what I have so far (which does work):

```
dynamic OSClass;
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString().StartsWith("5.1"))
{
    OSClass = new XP();
}
else
{
    OSClass = new Win7();
}
// Later on I use OSClass
OSClass.DoSomething();
```

However, because I'm using the dynamic keyword, Intellisense doesn't work. Is there any way of preserving (at least some of) Intellisense when I use one of the derivative classes later on?

I was thinking if I applied the interface to the "OSThingy" class and replace dynamic with "OSThingy", I would at least get Intellisense for methods and properties defined in "OSThingy", but not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

I'm sure the answer is yes, but is there a better way of branching code paths between Windows XP and Windows 7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have some methods on your implementations (defined on an interface) which are not defined on `OSThingy`. As I see it, you have a few choices of how to proceed.

**1. Move interface methods to `OSThingy`**

If your interface methods are applicable to every `OSThingy` implementation, then define the methods as abstract on `OSThingy`, e.g.

```
OSThingy osClass;
osClass = new XP();
osClass.Shutdown();
```

**2. Create a new base class derived from `OSThingy`**

Create a new class derived from `OSThingy`, e.g. `WindowsOSThingy` which contains the methods applicable just to Windows operating systems.

```
WindowsOSThingy osClass;
osClass = new XP();
osClass.StartTaskManager();
```

**3. Cast where appropriate**

Cast to your interface/base class when you need the methods of that type, e.g.

```
OSThingy osClass;
osClass = new XP();
IWindowsOS windowsOS = (IWindowsOS)osClass;
windowsOS.StartTaskManager();
```

You could make use of the `as` operator if you cannot be certain the type implements `IWindowsOS`, e.g.

```
OSThingy osClass;
osClass = new XP();
IWindowsOS windowsOS = osClass as windowsOS;
if(windowsOS != null)
    windowsOS.StartTaskManager();
```

**3. Make use of a generic method**

```
private void DoSomethingForWindowsOS<T>(T osClass) 
    where T : OSThing, IWindowsOS
{
    // Nonsense code
    osClass.StartTaskManager();
    osClass.Shutdown();
}
```

There are plenty of viable options without referring to the use of the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: Thank you Lukazoid! That is a really comprehensive explanation. I guess I have a few options to consider!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just write

```
OSThingy runningOS;
```

There's no reason to be using `dynamic` here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be declaring dynamic in this situation (in fact, very rarely). The differentiation is between a method or instance and a static method or instance. By default, classes and their methods are non-static (read: dynamic) unless you declare them static.

On a more IDE-level of looking at things, VS sometimes acts a bit funny with me and Intellisense will randomly quit working. Saving and restarting VS fixes this for me.

One more note, if you are going to be using this on an undetermined number of systems where you can't absolutely guarantee the OS version, you should provide for that in your code as well. Make sure you accomodate for minor versions also, as some people may not have the latest service packs installed and only trying to hit on 5.1 (SP1) would throw an exception if someone with 5.3 or 5.2 tries to use it (as well as 6.x for Vista, or 8.x for Windows 8)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment. FYI, my XP test system is SP3 but returns 5.1 for the version number. I believe 5.1.2600 is XP SP3.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. You would think they would use 5.1.xxxx to signify the minor patches released. Good 'ol Microsoft, never making sense haha

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking if I applied the interface to the "OSThingy" class and
>   replace dynamic with "OSThingy", I would at least get Intellisense for
>   methods and properties defined in "OSThingy", but not sure if this is
>   the right way to go about it.

This is a precisely way to go! It's one of the main benefits of inheriting a class/interface, that you can create multiple implementations of the same base and don't care about specifics while using them. If you need some specific methods/properties later on that belong only to a certain child class, all you need is to cast it to the correspondent type. I'd try to avoid `dynamic` altogether, unless absolutely necessary.

By the way, you don't have to use an interface here, you already have a base class which you can use `OSThingy`

Comment: Thanks Walther for the tip. I guess avoiding dynamic is the way to go! :)